# NoReverseMatch at /cart/remove/5/

Tags: python, django, web

This is my code. When I do not write `path('remove/<int:product_id>/', views.cart_detail, name='cart_remove'),`in `urls.py` it work fine but when I write the above code I get the following error:

> Reverse for 'cart_add' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart\/(?P[0-9]+)\/$']

The files:

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'cart'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:id>/', views.cart_add, name='cart_add'),
    path('remove/<int:product_id>/', views.cart_detail, name='cart_remove'),
    path('detail/', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),

]
```

**views.py**

```
def cart_add(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cart_form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
        if cart_form.is_valid():
            if not cart_form.cleaned_data['update']:
                product_id = str(id)
                session = request.session
                cart = session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
                if not cart:
                    cart = request.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]={}
                if product_id in cart:
                    cart[product_id]['quantity'] = cart_form.cleaned_data['quantity']
                else:
                    cart[product_id] = {'quantity': cart_form.cleaned_data['quantity']}
                session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = cart
                session.modified = True
            else:
                pass
    return redirect('shop:product_list')

def cart_detail(request, product_id=None):
    cart_item = request.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
    total_price = 0
    if not product_id:
        add = [k for k in cart_item.keys()]
        for key in add:
            product_id = int(key)
            product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
            total_price_per_item = cart_item[key]['quantity'] * product.price
            cart_item[key]['product'] = product
            cart_item[key]['total_price_per_item'] = total_price_per_item
            cart_item[key]['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(
                initial={'quantity': cart_item[key]['quantity'],
                         'update': True})
            total_price += total_price_per_item
    else:
        if product_id in cart_item:
            del cart_item[product_id]
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart_item, 'total_price': total_price})
```

**detail.html**

```
<td>
                    <form action="{% url 'cart:cart_add' product.id %}" method="post">
                        {{ item.update_quantity_form.quantity }}
                        {{ item.update_quantity_form.update }}
                        <input type="submit" value="Update">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'cart:cart_remove' product.id %}">Remove</a></td>
                <td class="num">${{ product.price }}</td>
                <td class="num">${{ item.total_price_per_item }}</td>
```

Comment: Could you show me the relevant part of the projects urls.py?

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),
    path('', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
]

Comment: from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),
    path('', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
]

Comment: I think i don't need that.

Comment: I think I got it:

In your form product.id is empty. In other words <int:id> is not provided, so the pattern does not match.

Comment: In detail.html i used product.name and product.price that works fine so why not product.id?

Comment: product.name and product.price are allowed to be empty. But product.id as an argument for the url not. To debug: strip out the URL part and just render the product.id like `PRODUCTID: {{ product.id }}` just to see if its there.

Comment: yes it is there.I check it.

Comment: is it an integer?

Comment: it work fine when i remove 'cart:cart_remove' url then  this error have been removed

Comment: yes it is integer

Comment: The code looks fine to me. I have the idea that you have stripped some parts to provide us a minimal working example. But that the actual bug is somewhere in the stripped out part.